# Retrieving data from database using php to html file

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to make a commenting system that saves a comment to MYSQL database and retrieve it once its submitted to the HTML form. I am pretty sure there is an easy way to do that but I cannot find anything specific on the internet.

So how is the basic way to retrieve something from a MYSQL database to HTML page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the beginning search for [PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo.php) tutorials. That is a quiet powerfull framework for database access.

> The PHP Data Objects (PDO) extension defines a lightweight, consistent
>   interface for accessing databases in PHP. Each database driver that
>   implements the PDO interface can expose database-specific features as
>   regular extension functions. Note that you cannot perform any database
>   functions using the PDO extension by itself; you must use a
>   database-specific PDO driver to access a database server.
>
> PDO provides a data-access abstraction layer, which means that,
>   regardless of which database you're using, you use the same functions
>   to issue queries and fetch data. PDO does not provide a database
>   abstraction; it doesn't rewrite SQL or emulate missing features. You
>   should use a full-blown abstraction layer if you need that facility.
>
> PDO ships with PHP 5.1, and is available as a PECL extension for PHP
>   5.0; PDO requires the new OO features in the core of PHP 5, and so will not run with earlier versions of PHP.

Comment: Thanks my friend I will look into it and if I got any problems I will ask again =)